# Ruby on Rails: Create Database Entry without JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, rest, web-applications, methods

i´m kinda new in web development and try to get started a project with Ruby on Rails (3.2.9).
So, i´m a little bit confused about what RoR can do without JavaScript or not...
For Example with using a Rails Scaffold, it´s no problem to create new records in the database via accessing the Controller´s new method (which then calls the create method and saves the record to the database)
I would now like to create new records without using a view for it. 
Just something like "User hits a button -> record is saved" 
I will give you an example (i need this for my studies, it´s not a real life project...)

I have a view which shows all my articles (rails generate scaffold article) and now  added a link to a "buy-method" which shows the articles name and available amount.
below there is a field in which a customer could select the amount of the article he wants to buy.

```
<p>
  <b>Name:</b>
  <%= @article.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Available:</b>
  <%= @article.stocks %>
</p>

<%= form_for(@article) do |f| %>

 <div class="field">
    <b>How many?</b>
    <br />
    <%= f.number_field :amount %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Now i want to add a link (or better a button i think) which causes an event which turns the article´s name and the selected amount into something like an order item i.e. create a record in an order_item table.

```
<td><%=link_to "Ja", :controller => "oderItem", :method => "create" %></td><br>
```

Now i´m confused about how i can do it.
I thought about using just the create - Method (or any method) of the Controller which does something like:

```
def match

    @apo = OrderItem.new(:amount :2, ...)
    @apo.save
end
```

But this just seems to render me to the new-method of the controller or sth like that.

So, with this explanations (which maybe as well reveal the level of my knowledge...) can anybody tell me if i am doing something really wrong with rails or if i just have to use javascript for this???

Some Sample Code (for Rails and / or JS) would be appreciated the most!
(Please keep it simple, i know that Ajax etc. are state of the Art but i just want to get this running :-) )
...also links to Code-Samples which just show projects like this on Rails (simply :-) ) would be very nice!

Comment: So if I'm understanding this correctly, when a user updates the amount field then clicks "buy," you want the user to be taken to a purchase form that knows what the user is buying, and how many, is that correct?

Comment: Ah I see, you want the form to appear in place...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to change the the page layout to show a "mini" form in response to a user clicking a particular element, you're going to either need to render a new view, or modify the current document via JavaScript.

Here's a simplified version of what this view code might look like if you opted to reveal a form via JavaScript:

ERB:

```
# rendering each available article...
<% @articles.each do |article| %>

  <p>
    <b>Name:</b>
    <%= article.name %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <b>Available:</b>
    <%= article.stocks %>
  </p>

  <% button_tag(:type => 'button', :class => 'buy-btn', data-article-id="article.id") do %>
    <strong>Buy Me!</strong>
  <% end %>

  # for each article, create a mini form with which
  # the user can buy n of said article...
  <div class="field hidden-item" id="form-#{article.id}" >
    <%= form_for(OrderItem.new do |f| %>   
      <b>How many?</b>
      <br />
      <%= f.number_field_tag :amount%>
      <%= f.submit %>    
    <% end %> 
  </div>
<% end %>
```

CSS:

```
.field {
  display: none; //hides the div from all browsers by default
}
```

JavaScript to help tie everything together:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //... other js code

  // bind all elements with the css class 'buy-btn' to 
  // a click event...
  $(".buy-btn").bind('click', function() {
      var id = $(this).data('article-id');
      $("#form-" + id).slideDown(); // shows the selected element with a nice slide down effect
  });

  //... other js code

});
```

So in the ERB we supply each article with a mini-form waiting to be populated and submitted. The form is hidden by default in our CSS, to be made visible when the user clicks the "Buy Me!" button for the article in question.

This approach can also be adjusted a bit to allow the user to order however many different articles they desire by moving the the form declarations around a bit, and with appropriate handling in the OrderItemsController.create action.

Another thing to keep in mind is that clicking the submit button on a form will cause the page to redirect by default. That's probably how you'll want to leave it while just getting started, but when you start to become comfortable, check out how to use `:remote => true` on submit tags to allow submitting forms in the background via AJAX.

If you REALLY want to do it without any JavaScript at all, you're going to either have to do some very advanced work with CSS or will have to rig a link that passes a parameter to your view that instructs it to show a particular form. Here's what that might look like:

```
# rendering each available article, as before...
<% @articles.each do |article| %>

  <p>
    <b>Name:</b>
    <%= article.name %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <b>Available:</b>
    <%= article.stocks %>
  </p>

  # ... but now set up a link that passes a param to the controller...
  <%= link_to( 'Buy Me!', "/articles?article=#{article.id}" ) %>

  # which we then use to render a form on the page if the id in the
  # 'article' param matches the id of the article we are currently
  # rendering...
  <% if params[:article] && params[:article] == article.id %>

    <%= form_for(OrderItem.new do |f| %>   
      <b>How many?</b>
      <br />
      <%= f.number_field_tag :amount%>
      <%= f.submit %>    
    <% end %> 
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This may not be exact, but I hope it points you in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

Ruby on Rails does not depend on Javascript and therefore you don't need to know Javascript to learn Ruby and Rails.

To answer one of your questions the `link_to` `method` doesn't refer to which action you are trying to call but to the HTTP method such as "POST", "GET", "PUT", "DELETE". You should use `:action` to tell which action in the controller (methods) to go to.

There are a few places that can get you started with Ruby and Rails.

- [Code School](http://codeschool.com) - Code school has a few free courses and one of them happens to be a very good one on Ruby on Rails
- [Code Academy](http://codeacademy.com) - Code academy is more structured than code school and still provides many courses on different web development technologies
- [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com) - Railscasts is a great site with some free videos of rails tutorials

Maybe some people can elaborate on more sources. Also, [Github](http://github.com) has many open source projects that you can take a look at and have a feel on how people use Ruby and Rails.

Comment: +1 for providing great places to start. Railscasts in particular has been a godsend for me.

Comment: I now just used a button calling a method... <%= button_to "yes          ", :controller => :apos, 
                           :method => :match %>

Comment: Since you are using a form you could use `submit` to send that form to your app. I'm sorry I wasn't able to help much with your code specific but I'm sure if you go through those links I provided and follow their tutorials you'll have a better understanding of how Rails works.